# Catching errors using async/await for async and sync functions

Tags: node.js, exception, async-await

I have a router that needs to be able to call both async functions as well as sync functions.   I have set up the following code as the executor:

```
async exec(method, path, params, payload) {
    const route = this.get(method, path);

    if (!route) throw new RequestError(422, 'Route [' + path + '] not found');

    // Recheck, just to make sure
    if (typeof route._callback !== 'function')
        throw new AppError('Callback defined for route [' + route.name + '] is not a function');

    this._logger('info', 'Route [' + path + '] recieved.  Executing [' + route.callback + ']', route.params);

    let results;
    try {
        results = route._callback(Object.assign(params || {}, route.params || {}), payload);
        // If the results is a promise, then we await the promise results
        if (results.then && typeof results.then === 'function') {
            await results;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        throw new AppError(err.message, err);
    }

    return results;
}
```

In the calling function, I have several functions which have two different potential areas where an error can be thrown.   One is outside of a Promise.All and the other is inside.

```
async myFunction(params,payload) {

    // This function can throw an error if the database 
    // connection goes bad
    if( await this._checkExists(this.conn, params) )
        return { code: 2, message: 'Already Exists' };

    if ((await this._regCount(this.conn, params)) === 0) {
        Promise.all([
            this._sendMail(params), 
            this._notify(params),
            this._update(params)
        });

        return { code: 1, message: 'Success' };
    }
}
```

Because the router is part of a library and the `myFunction` is a user function that I don't have control over, I would like the router to be able to catch any exceptions that occur within myFunction (or any of its inner functions).   I don't want the user to be forced to write try/catch blocks internally.   I want them to bubble up to the router's internal error reporting functions.

With the current code structure, if I throw an error within myFunction, then the catch in the router's `exec` function works fine.    However, if an error is thrown within any of the internal functions (i.e. `_checkExists` or `_sendMail`), etc, then I get the UnhandledRejection error.

What is the proper way to trap for this within the router's `exec` function?

Answer (score 0):

The router code is fine.   I ended up re-structuring the myFunction to be:

```
async myFunction(params,payload) {

    // This function can throw an error if the database 
    // connection goes bad
    if( await this._checkExists(this.conn, params) )
        return { code: 2, message: 'Already Exists' };

    if ((await this._regCount(this.conn, params)) > 0)
        return { code: 1, message: 'Already Exists' };

    Promise.all([
        this._sendMail(params), 
        this._notify(params),
        this._update(params)
    });

    return { code: 1, message: 'Success' };
}
```

Which I am not exactly sure why it would make a difference.   Granted, the above code would have not returned anything if there was an exception thrown in regCount, but not sure why that would have bubbled up into an UnhandledRejection.

Problem has been resolved, but the async/await seems rather finicky that if you don't get it just right, you can run into problems with dealing with promises.

RANT:  If ECMA would just solve the core issue of being able to run multithreaded instead of trying to make everything work in a single thread, we wouldn't have to go through all this async pain.  Give us threads and we can choose where and when we want sync versus async.

....ok, stepping down from my soapbox.